# Android Mediaplayer error (1, -2147483648) using libmedia

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use libmedia to play encoded videos on Android, but I receive this unknown error (1, -2147483648) on Mediaplayer i.e. VideoView

My code for video is

```
        mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();
        c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        SecretKey skey = new SecretKeySpec("password".getBytes(),
                "AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
        mServer.setCipher(c);
        mServer.start();
        String path = mServer.getURL("asset://video.mp4");
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)); 
        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.start();
```

The problem isn't in my code because even when I try to run sample application from [here](http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/download/), I still get the same error, not just for encrypted but normal video as well.